# Google Places radar search (radius) returning wrong results

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using google places radius search for finding out the places/points inside a radius but somehow it is returning results which are outside the circle.

Here the demo: http://jsbin.com/bobumora/1/

I have checked it by drawing a circle of same radius with google circle api and calculating by Haversine formula too. There distance from the centre is greater than the radius of the circle as well as radius which I used for the search

Note: I think the circle should not distort as the centre is relatively near to the equator and zoom level is 14.

Update 1

Code for drawing circle is

```
var populationOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.1,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.075,
  map: map,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.269310, 81.603152),
  radius: 3050
};
// Add the circle for this city to the map.
cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
```

and code for radar search is

```
function performSearch() {
 var request = {
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(21.269310, 81.603152),
        radius: 3050,
        types: ["grocery_or_supermarket", "home_goods_store",
            "department_store", "clothing_store", "convenience_store"]
      };
 service.radarSearch(request, callback);
}
```

I am setting radius as 3050 for both the circle and radar search.

Comment: Can you post some code with your answer. If it's not producing a radial search on the map it could be because the radius to search is larger than the circle's circumference or its searching from point to point which that could end up being square, like a box.

Comment: Let's assume that the location/radius-combination defines a preferred area for the returned results, but did not limit the results to this area(the documentation didn't state that for radarSearch, but it does e.g. for a textSearch )